# How to inject a UseCase in another UseCase in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I've got two UseCases named, `FirstUseCase` and `SecondUseCase`.
**FirstUseCases**

```
export class FirstUsecases {
  constructor(
    private readonly something: Something
) {}

  async execute(): Promise<any> {
    console.log("This is FirstUsecases class.");
  }
}
```

**SecondUseCases**

```
export class SecondUsecases {
  constructor(
              // How to inject FirstUsecases here?
              private readonly firstUseCases: FirstUsecases ) {}

  async execute(): Promise<any> {
    this.firstUseCases.execute();
  }
}
```

I wanna inject `FirstUsecases` into the `SecondUsecases` class. 
**Note:** the  `FirstUsecases` and `SecondUsecases` are in the same module named `MyProxyModule`.
**MyProxyModule**

```
static register(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: MyProxyModule,
        providers: [
        {
          inject: [FirstRepository],
          provide: "FIRST_USECASE",
          useFactory: (firstRepository: FirstRepository) => new FirstUsecases(firstRepository),
        },
        {
          inject: [SecondRepository],
          provide: "SECOND_USECASE",
          useFactory: (secondRepository: SecondRepository) => new SecondUsecases(secondRepository),
        },,
      ]
    }
}
```

How can I inject `FirstUsecases` into `SecondUsecases`?

Comment: what's wrong with using `@Inject("FIRST_USECASE")`? I didn't follow. That's pretty much covered in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `new` like that, you're in charge of passing the dependencies the class needs. To get an instance of the `FirstUsecases` you can add its injection token to the `inject` array, like how you added `SecondRepository` and then pass it on to the constructor.

```js
static register(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: MyProxyModule,
        providers: [
        {
          inject: [FirstRepository],
          provide: "FIRST_USECASE",
          useFactory: (firstRepository: FirstRepository) => new FirstUsecases(firstRepository),
        },
        {
          inject: [SecondRepository "FIRST_USECASE"],
          provide: "SECOND_USECASE",
          useFactory: (secondRepository: SecondRepository, firstUsecase: FirstUsercase) => new SecondUsecases(secondRepository, firstUsecase),
        },,
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: may explain if ```FirstUsecases``` has a constructor, how to inject it in ```SecondRepository```  ?
I've updated my question.

Comment: @HosseinSafari you're injecting `FirstUsecases` into `SecondRepository`? Why?

Comment: I wanna use usecase composition.  actually, I wanna use two different Usecses in the third Usecase.

Comment: I still don't follow.

Comment: ohhhh I'm sp surry, I wrote wrong.
I mean: may explain if ```FirstUsecases``` has a constructor, how to inject it in ```SecondUsecases```?

Comment: Just like I showed above. Was something not clear about that? The `inject` array tells Nest what to pass to the `useFactory` method, in this case an instance of `SecondRepository` and the value that the `FIRST_USECASE` points to (an instance of `FirstUsecases`). So now we can pass these dependencies on to `SecondUsecases` as shown